# How can I move an outlet from the back of an enclosed space to the front wall?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I have a built-in cabinet that has an outlet at the back to power a TV.  I am looking at framing over that built-in opening to create a flat wall to mount a larger flat panel TV.  I want to move the existing outlet from the back of the built-in to the new 'wall.'

What is the best/right way to do this? Can I replace the existing box with a junction box and run wire along a framing member to a new box? The depth of the cabinet is ballpark  24".

The first picture shows a set of cabinet doors. The TV is behind the doors. I want to remove the doors, fill in the opening with drywall, and add an outlet so that I can mount a TV.

[image: Outside]

[image: Inside]

Comment: What's on the other side of the wall with the existing outlet?

Comment: Is the fireplace below still in use?  If not, you could get a lot more space back by removing the whole structure.

Answer (score 19):

If moving the outlet forward makes the cable to it shorter, no problem. If you need to add cable, you either need to go back to the next junction box and fish a new cable, or you need to make the junction at the old outlet box accessible (without tools) which might be as simple as punching through the wall (depending what's on the other side of it) and mounting the box facing that way with a blank cover.

*Accessible without tools* means you can **find** the junction box without unscrewing anything, smashing open drywall, etc. It's expected that a screwdriver is needed to *open* it. It can be behind a door or a painting or something that conceals it but is movable without using tools to move it.

But, I'd counsel a rethink before you make that perfectly useful space an inaccessible void. Easy enough to put some lumber to support a TV mount across the front but leave most of the opening so you can swing the TV away and get to the space behind, then make the hole in the wall vanish by swinging the TV back in place - and that means the present outlet box is accessible. You can use also use the space for any TV-related equipment that doesn't require frequent access or line-of-sight remote control.

Comment: +1 to the final paragraph in particular. I can think of several ways to keep it usable, all of which would allow you to simply plug your TV into the original outlet.

Comment: I agree...this may be the simplest way to go. I may be overthinking it.